# Unable to get all the content of the page in Jmeter responses

Tags: jmeter

Unable to get all the content of the page in Jmeter responses (even not available in view page source)

We have scenario where need to assert the content displayed on the web page, this content/text doesn't show up in 'view page source' as well and not shows in the Jmeter response too.

Looks like this content/text is getting generated dynamically from .js file at the run time.

However if inspect the text element, it shows in DOM (F12>Elements).

Is it possible to get this kind of dynamically generated text by .js file through Jmeter response and assert.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve this by using Jmeter with Selenium, launched the browser and performed the scenario so that the run time page/all .js/dynamically generated data is captured under Jmeter responses and could assert.

Thanks for help.